# "Uncaught ReferenceError" when using Soundcloud API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm trying to use Javascript to search for tracks on Soundcloud using the site's API.  I have created a page `test.html` with the following code (client ID removed):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js">
function findMusicByTag(tag)
{
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
});
SC.get('/tracks',{tags:\"tag\"},
    function(tracks)
    {
        console.log(tracks);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="findMusicByTag('hitech')">
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page in Chrome, then go to the console, I see this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: findMusicByTag is not defined         test.html:17
```

What's wrong with the way I'm defining `findMusicByTag()`?

Comment: which line is line 17?

Comment: Separate your `<script>` into two: one for `src`, one for your script.

Comment: @AlexMarchant, line 17 is the `<body onload="findMusicByTag('hitech')">` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate your `<script>` tag into two:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function findMusicByTag(tag)
{
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
    });
    SC.get('/tracks',{tags:tag},
        function(tracks)
        {
            console.log(tracks);
    });
}
</script>
```

As mentioned by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script):

> **src**
>
> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a
>   document. **`script` elements with an `src` attribute specified should not
>   have a script embedded within its tags**.

**Edit**: removed the back slashes and double quote around `{tags:tag}`.

Comment: I separated the script tag block into two `<script></script>` blocks, but got the same error.

Comment: @sigil Do you notice other error? The overall function definition seems fine, so if it keep saying that the function is undefined, it may be that there's some other error that prevents JS from further parsing.

Comment: Ok, now it works.  I think I was getting the same error after removing the quotes because i was still loading the original unaltered copy of the page.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to separating the script tags, you need to remove the /" around tag

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function findMusicByTag(tag)
{
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'your id'
});
SC.get('/tracks',{tags: tag},
    function(tracks)
    {
        console.log(tracks);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="findMusicByTag('hitech')">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I removed the escaped quotes, but got the same error.  Separated the script tags as well.